# How to draw arrows to show linked data between records in two TcxGrid?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid, devexpress-windows-ui

I have two grids (TcxGrid) in my application, each one in a side of the form. Both grids show linked data, although they could be scrolled vertically separatedly.
I want to draw arrows in the middle panel, showing the line of the other grid that the record is linked to, like this example:

```
GridA   GridB
+---+   +---+
| a |---| a |
| b |   | i |
| c |\  | h |
| d | \ | g |
| e |  \| h |
| f |   | b |
+---+   +---+
```

The draw proccess are simple. My trouble is with identify the record positions.
How do I discover what is the vertical position of each grid row/record, considering that could have grouping in both grids?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depending how you're implementing it, the TcxCustomGridRecord.Index may help?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I am scanning all records using a loop in GridA.DataController.RecordCount and using the method GetRowIndexByRecordIndex to obtain the row (that is different than record), thus I can call ViewInfo.RecordsViewInfo[iRow].ContentBounds. This works fine if I have no vertical scroll (few records). But if I start scrolling it doesn't find the lasts records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that the vertical position of a grid's record can be obtained in this way:

The grid view has the property `ViewData.Rows`. `Rows` is an array and each element of it has the `RecordIndex` property. So you can iterate over the `Rows` array and test if its `RecordIndex` is which the one you are finding and, if true, get the property `ViewInfo.ClientBounds.Top`.

Example:

```
for i := 0 to gdMovimentoTV.ViewData.RowCount - 1 do 
  if gdMovimentoTV.ViewData.Rows[i].RecordIndex = iSomeRecordIndex then begin
    if Assigned(gdMovimentoTV.ViewData.Rows[i].ViewInfo) then begin
      Result := gdMovimentoTV.ViewData.Rows[i].ViewInfo.ClientBounds.Top;
      Break;
    end;
```